# pandas - restructuring dataframe using column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I read in the following DataFrame, where I have many columns similar to S&PCOMP with a (PO) and (PI) tail at the end of the column name.

```
                      Date         S&PCOMP(PO)         S&PCOMP(PI)  NASA100(PO)    NASA100(PI)
0      1978-09-13 00:00:00                 nan              106.34  someValue      someValue 
1      1978-09-14 00:00:00                 nan  105.10000000000001  someValue      someValue
2      1978-09-15 00:00:00                 nan              104.12   
3      1978-09-18 00:00:00                 nan  103.21000000000001   
4      1978-09-19 00:00:00                 nan              102.53   
5      1978-09-20 00:00:00                 nan              101.73   
6      1978-09-21 00:00:00                 nan               101.9   
7      1978-09-22 00:00:00                 nan              101.84   
8      1978-09-25 00:00:00                 nan              101.86   
9      1978-09-26 00:00:00                 nan              102.62   
10     1978-09-27 00:00:00                 nan              101.66
```

I want to restructure this using regex and multi-indexing, into the following DataFrame, for every single column name. Essentially, I use the PO and PI values as 2 columns and expand my DF vertically using the column name base as an index. As you can see, the dates roll... meaning that for every unique column name base I'd have the same set of days.

```
                      Date                      Open               Close
S&PCOMP      1978-09-13 00:00:00                 nan              106.34   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-14 00:00:00                 nan  105.10000000000001   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-15 00:00:00                 nan              104.12   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-18 00:00:00                 nan  103.21000000000001   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-19 00:00:00                 nan              102.53   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-20 00:00:00                 nan              101.73   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-21 00:00:00                 nan               101.9   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-22 00:00:00                 nan              101.84   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-25 00:00:00                 nan              101.86   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-26 00:00:00                 nan              102.62   
S&PCOMP      1978-09-27 00:00:00                 nan              101.66
NASA100      1978-09-13 00:00:00                 someValue        someValue   
NASA100      1978-09-14 00:00:00                 someValue        someValue
```

What would be the easiest way of accomplishing this with pandas? Could I use regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
values = [['1978-09-13 0:00', 'someValue', 106.34, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-14 0:00', 'someValue', 105.1, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-15 0:00', 'someValue', 104.12, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-18 0:00', 'someValue', 103.21, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-19 0:00', 'someValue', 102.53, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-20 0:00', 'someValue', 101.73, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-21 0:00', 'someValue', 101.9, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-22 0:00', 'someValue', 101.84, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-25 0:00', 'someValue', 101.86, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-26 0:00', 'someValue', 102.62, 'someValue', 'someValue'],
       ['1978-09-27 0:00', 'someValue', 101.66, 'someValue', 'someValue']]

headers = ['Date', 'S&PCOMP(PO)', 'S&PCOMP(PI)', 'NASA100(PO)', 'NASA100(PI)']

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=headers)
```

if you can change the headers - **the following loop, generates the new headers** (the new headers are not hand-coded):

```
headers_new = {}
for x in list(df.columns):
    headers_new[x] = x[-4:] + x[:-4]
```

`headers_new` is the output of the preceding loop.

```
headers_new =
{'Date': 'Date',
 'S&PCOMP(PO)': '(PO)S&PCOMP',
 'S&PCOMP(PI)': '(PI)S&PCOMP',
 'NASA100(PO)': '(PO)NASA100',
 'NASA100(PI)': '(PI)NASA100'}

df = df.rename(index=str, columns=headers_new)
```

then you can:

```
df_long = pd.wide_to_long(df, ['(PO)', '(PI)'], i='Date', j='stock', suffix=r'(?<=\))(.*)')


                             (PO)     (PI)
           Date   stock     
1978-09-13 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   106.34
1978-09-14 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   105.1
1978-09-15 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   104.12
1978-09-18 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   103.21
1978-09-19 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   102.53
1978-09-20 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   101.73
1978-09-21 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   101.9
1978-09-22 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   101.84
1978-09-25 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   101.86
1978-09-26 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   102.62
1978-09-27 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   101.66
1978-09-13 0:00 NASA100 someValue   someValue
1978-09-14 0:00 NASA100 someValue   someValue
```

**Indexing**

```
df.columns = 
Index(['(PO)', '(PI)'], dtype='object')

df.loc[('1978-09-25 0:00')] = 

             (PO)       (PI)
  stock     
S&PCOMP someValue   101.86
NASA100 someValue   someValue

df.loc[('1978-09-25 0:00', 'S&PCOMP')] = 
(PO)    someValue
(PI)       101.86
Name: (1978-09-25 0:00, S&PCOMP), dtype: object

# or you can reset the index:

df2 = df.reset_index()

df2.columns =
Index(['Date', 'stock', '(PO)', '(PI)'], dtype='object')

df2.iloc[:3]

               Date   stock      (PO)     (PI)
0   1978-09-13 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   106.34
1   1978-09-14 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   105.1
2   1978-09-15 0:00 S&PCOMP someValue   104.12
```

- Also see [Data Reshaping with Pandas Explained](https://medium.com/@wangyuw/data-reshaping-with-pandas-explained-80b2f51f88d2)